# Return Data on showwebpopup

Tags: coronasdk

well i have this native.showWebPopup when we use "corona:close" as form action it will close the native.showWebPopup now my question.

is it possible to return some data back to corona when i use the form "corona:close"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, and this should work:

In your html page add something like this (+javascript to change val if you will):

```
<a href="corona:close?val=122">PROCESS</a>
```

And in your listener function add this to get the value:

```
if string.find(event.url,"corona") then
    print("val is " .. string.sub(event.url,18))
end
```

Do you know the newWenView object?

http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/native/newWebView.html

Hope this helps